# mysql compare values again generated column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this table with 2 columns first and second. I want to compare
a value against the sum of the 2 columns. how do i do that?

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first INT,
    second INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into test2(first,second) values (3,4);
insert into test2(first,second) values (13,14);
insert into test2(first,second) values (23,24);


SET @mintotal := 20;

select first + second as total from test2;//works well

select first + second as total from test2 where total > @mintotal;  //sql error, unknown column total. expecting 2nd and 3d data row to be returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generated Column like So

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test2`;
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sum` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`first` + `second`)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into test2(first,second) values (3,4);
insert into test2(first,second) values (13,14);
insert into test2(first,second) values (23,24);
```

Now every time u insert value for `first` and `second`, `Sum` would = `first` + `second`...

```
Select * From test2 where Sum >  @mintotal;
```

Note: If you do not want to have a generated column as above, you can fix the following query..

```
select first + second as total from test2 WHERE total > @mintotal;
```

Into

```
select first + second as total from test2 HAVING total > @mintotal;
```

you have to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`